# Is it secure enough to put SQL Queries into sql.properties file for SpringBoot app

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am externalizing my SQL queries into .properties file using SpringBoot App with Java 8.

I just want to know how secure is it to put all my Queries into .properties file

Inside the resources folder, I have a file called queries.properties inside file I have below items

```
query1=EXEC [NHistory] @vchrId = ?
query2= EXEC [CDetails] @vchrID = ?
query3=EXEC[LDetails]
```

Comment: why do you need that in the first place? you should use spring repositories /spring data to form your queries

Comment: you keep your db credentials in properties file.. keeping queries in properties file is not a problem unless you control access.

Comment: @Hasson I have very complex queries with many joins. It's very hard to achieve same with spring data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't do this.**

This isn't best practice and might create security issues, but not necessarily for the reasons you think, e.g. accidentally serving the file.

It looks like you might be tempted to create SQL by replacing the `?` marker, which will expose you to SQL injection.

It also makes your code harder to read, as it breaks object oriented encapsulation, as all your SQL is mixed together.

Instead create proper repositories using Spring Data's existing functionality for creating custom SQL, which also does not expose you to SQL injection (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query).

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE u.status = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
User findUserByStatusNative(Integer status);
```

Spring Data also saves you from having to manually use `JDBCTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexB I will follow best practice as you mention above

Comment: @Pankaj Sonani Thank you. However the way to say thank you on Stackoverflow is to accept / or upvote an answer, so feel free to do so here, if you choose.